# В чем разница между возвращением из API-контроллера IActionResult и конкретного объекта?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Собственно, в чем разница и что лучше использовать повсеместно и в каких случаях?

Вроде, результат будет в обоих случаях один и тот же...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для приложения, которое будет пользоваться этим API разницы нет, а для контроллера это необходимо чтобы иметь возможность возвращать разные ответы (status code). Например:

```cs
public User GetUser(int id)
{
    // ...
    return user;
}
```

ничего плохого в таком коде нет, но если мы захотим отправить `NotFound` или `BadRequest` или другой код, нам компилятор не позволит, т.к. типы будут не сходиться, для этого и был придуман "общий" интерфейс `IActionResult` и его реализации: `ActionResult<T>`, `OkResult`, `NotFoundResult` и т.д. Это позволяет писать такой код:

```cs
public ActionResult<User> GetUser(int id)
{
    if (/* тут может быть некая валидация */)
        return BadRequest(); // возвращает BadRequestResult, т.е. код 400 

    if (/* ... */)
        return NotFound(); // возвращает NotFoundResult, т.е. код 404

    // ...
    return user; // код 200, все ок
}
```

Фреймворк распознает эти типы и понимает как это правильно отправлять пользователю.

И ещё, лучше использовать вместо "чистого" интерфейса `IActionResult` его реализацию - `ActionResult<T>`. Это немного упрощает код, т.к. вместо `return Ok(user);` вы можете писать просто `return user`.

Подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-3.1).